# retrofit2 exception : Unable to start activity ComponentInfo

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2

Hi iam using retrofit 2 to download and parse a JSON file to a model class 
in my code but i gave a bunch of exception about it here is my error related code:

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl("http://services.hanselandpetal.com").addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();

    getFlowers getFlowers = retrofit.create(getFlowers.class);
    Call<Flowers> call = getFlowers.all();

        Response <Flowers> response = call.execute();
```

this is my interface

```
public interface FlowerAPI {
@GET("feeds/flowers.json")
Call<List<Flower>> getAllFlowers();
```

}

and these are exception stack:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.uefi.retet/com.example.uefi.retet.MainActivity}: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2646)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
               Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
                  at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1303)
                  at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupHostByName(Inet6AddressImpl.java:86)
                  at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Inet6AddressImpl.java:74)
```

appreciate your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing network call on MainThread by calling `call.execute()` instead use `call.enqueue(callback)` it executes network call on worker thread and gives back response through callback on MainThread.

For more info: https://square.github.io/retrofit/2.x/retrofit/retrofit2/Call.html

Comment: thanks for your help but I got various errors on Callback<flower> section